# Will I be barred from traveling to the US in the future, after a tense immigration interrogation?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I am a solo British traveler (born in the UK with British citizenship), was pulled into a secondary assessment room after arriving. I was admitted, but will that hurt my chance of re-entry next time?

I am assuming it was because I told the initial CBP officer I am self-employed/freelancer (which is true), look like a young Saddam Hussein and was a bit cagey with my answers to what I was doing. I was in a grumpy and nervous mood.

I have absolutely no intention or desire to live or work in the US, but I certainly would want to visit again. Does this mean my passport is forever flagged from now on? Should I just get a "real job"? Would it be wiser to not travel alone in the future?

I noticed the CBP officer in the secondary assessment room taking notes. Wish I could prove to them that I really did leave with my return flight ticket after my holiday.

Comment: Were you admitted or sent back?

Comment: I was admitted.

Comment: Can you edit that in to the questions please, what the eventual decision was is *very* important for an accurate answer.

Comment: Personal anecdote - I've been "secondary interviewed" (and admitted) once in the past. It doesn't seem to have had any impact on my travels to the USA after that point and didn't prevent me from receiving an H1B, followed by a "green card".

Comment: Don't take it personally, they do that to a lot of people. I had a colleague, a respectable Spanish engineer, who insisted on looking like the bad Mexicans in cowboy movies. He got hauled in every time, and once got kept overnight and had to be freed by his consul.

Comment: @brhans secondary inspection _per se_ is not a guarantee of future problems, but it could be a symptom of something else that could cause future problems.  From our perspective, it's difficult to say which it is here.  My wife and I were once "randomly selected" driving into the US from Canada (in a car we had rented in the US).  The appearance of the people in the waiting room suggested that they were not randomly selected, but the fact that nothing like this happened to us again suggests that it may indeed have been random in our case.

Comment: "Wish I could prove to them that I really did leave with my return flight ticket after my holiday." Don't worry about this; they already know. The reason that the U.S. does not have an exit immigration control is simply that CBP already knows who is on every international flight that leaves. They get a copy of the flight manifest.

Comment: Another statistical datum: on a domestic flight after going through an x-ray machine (I have pre-check), one of my 10-year-old, very blond sons was flagged for a pat-down. The x-ray machine alerted twice--he wasn't carrying anything and didn't even have pockets. The TSA agent said it was a random flag. I **immediately** thought of y'all.

Comment: And yet another: I recently flew out of Heathrow (London, UK) and was flagged for X-ray and pat-down. The very friendly agent who did this told me it was because I had a slight sweat. Apparently, they have something that can detect that (I was barely aware of it myself, I was just slightly hot because I was wearing a jacket).

Answer (score 56):

Given that you were admitted, you have no reason to think you will be barred in the future.  There's a good chance that you can expect to be pulled into secondary inspection on future visits, however, as you probably have a flag in your record.

> Wish I could prove to them that I really did leave with my return flight ticket after my holiday.

If you fly out of the US, the airline will report your departure.  If you cross into Canada, the Canadian border service will do the same.  If you leave through Mexico, you'll have to tell them yourself.  You can keep track of your record at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov -- there are instructions there for reporting your departure if they don't pick it up automatically.

Comment: Perhaps try to look a bit less like - um - a person of interest.

Comment: @RedSonja are you talking about hair/beard styles? If so, I would not change my appearance to fight against discrimination. That would be giving in to it.

Comment: @infinitezero hair and beard are not the only factors, of course, but I am reminded of my only experience in "secondary", driving into New York from Ontario; most of the people there looked Central American. A group of women had head coverings. Some orthodox priests came in, and I wondered whether they had been mistaken for Muslims because of their long beards and cassocks. Or maybe they knew full well that they were priests -- they wore crosses after all. Anyway, it was only for customs (I'm a US citizen and my wife a UN officer), so they searched the car and then we were on our way.

Comment: @infinitezero While profiling may not be "PC", it's certainly helped Israel keep El Al flights from being hijacked since the late 70s. If you intentionally choose to put yourself through the rigamarole, you're certainly free to do so, just don't complain about it. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan Do you have any proof, that profiling causautes no hijacks? Or is this just mere speculation? Also, I like having a long beard and long hair. I grew it like this because **I like it**, not because I *choose to put myself through the rigamarole*. I sincerely hope you are not suggesting this.

Comment: @FreeMan from what I understand of Israeli profiling (which may well be propaganda; I don't know), it is rather more sophisticated than simple discrimination on the basis of appearance.  I am unaware of any such sophistication in US measures.  (For example, if September 2001 is any guide, clean-shaven Arab men with short hair are more likely to intend harm than men with long hair and beards; I also remember "random" searches after that in Europe that were the opposite of random -- only people of non-European appearance were searched, and all such people were searched.)

Comment: Adding to @phoog: El Al's "profiling", while probably racial at times, is far more involved than merely "do they look swarthy?"/"are they dressed in Muslim religious attire?" (among other things, many Jewish Israelis are visually and linguistically indistinguishable from Israeli Arabs; even if El Al wanted to, they can't just use a color swatch for racial/racist profiling like they can in the U.S.). They use "predictive profiling", where they essentially hire cold readers to quiz passengers before the flight, looking for discrepancies in their story, hesitation, unusual nervousness, etc.

Comment: To be clear, I've been through it a couple times, so I have some experience (admittedly from the perspective of a white Jewish man, so I can't say if it's *worse* for PoC). It was an interesting experience; the interview zigs and zags, presumably to make it harder to prepare for it if your story isn't so practiced it's as easy to tell as the truth. At one point, having determined I was Jewish (I'm not readily visually identifiable as such, but I was going on a Birthright Israel trip at the time), I was asked to sing the Sh'ma off the cuff. Not a normal security interview by any means.

Comment: @ShadowRanger As a white, American non-jew (Christian in my case,) my experience was that they were sending quite a lot of solo travelers (including me) to more intensive security screening. They swabbed everything in my carry-on for explosives, had to take off belt and shoes to go through security, etc. They had a dedicated security line just for the more intensive screenings at TLV (this was at security, well after the pre-check-in interview.) And, obviously, I wasn't doing anything shady in Israel. I was there with a tour, but just taking a separate flight out to spend some time in Europe.

Comment: @infinitezero I neither endorse or condemn FreeMan's comment but it's worth noting that it's impossible to prove a negative. You can never definitively say that doing X prevented Y, only show a correlation that after starting to do X the data shows Y stopped happening as often or at all.

Comment: @infinitezero While proving it prevented a hijacking would obviously be impossible it **has** without question prevented a bombing.  The dupe had no idea she was carrying a bomb.  They also "caught" the shoe bomber--since it was a trial run they didn't find anything and allowed him to fly, but with an air marshal sitting next to him.

Comment: @LorenPechtel If you're talking about the case I'm thinking of, profiling did not prevent a bombing; the pregnant ethnically Irish woman unknowingly carrying a bomb who was stopped before boarding an El Al flight matched none of the standard profiles.

Comment: @prosfilaes It wasn't profiling per se, but rather that they asked her questions that revealed she might be a dupe.  I was addressing the general issue of the effectiveness of their questioning, not in how they select who to question.

Comment: I see that the comments have gone on a tangent to discuss El Al security measures. To those who have never flown El Al, _everybody_ is questioned and the "profiling" is based on answers, not appearance. I'm a light-skinned Israeli Jew of European ancestry who has served in infantry and like everybody else I get questioned and screened - it happens while one is on line to the ticket counter. And yes, the one time I stumbled and backtracked because I remembered a detail mid-conversation, I was much further scrutinized. **There is certain profiling, but it is not racial profiling.**

Comment: Stopping people at random will prevent some bombings, you need more evidence and statistics to prove that profiling is more effective than chance.

Answer (score 14):

I was pulled into secondary once as a Hungarian citizen and Canadian resident and a few months later I applied for and got my NEXUS card. Not only you do not get barred just because of a secondary, you do not even become ineligible for Trusted Traveler programs. (UK citizens are eligible for Global Entry.)

Admittedly, if I resemble anyone famous, that would be probably be Humpty Dumpty.

Answer (score 6):

A way to increase your chances of admission on your next visit is to explicitly and proactively address as many the red (or orange, yellow ;-) ) flags as you can.

The officer's two main concerns (apart from you being a Nazi, plan a terrorist attack or sell illegal drugs) are:

- You may want to stay in the country and not return home, that is, immigrate illegally. The main argument against that are ties to your place of residence at home.
- Even if you actually will return, you may need to or want to work illegally during your stay. The main argument against that is loads of money in your bank that you can access with a credit or debit card.

What you want to avoid is appearing as an outright work migrant or as a hippie, a drifter with neither plan nor money who is likely to strand in the U.S.

The impression that you are instead a legit tourist can be instilled in the officer by presenting corroborating evidence. Examples are listed below. None of them is absolute proof of your intentions — it's rather that you tell a consistent, plausible story that fits with facts you present.

- Have a **return ticket.** Print out your E-ticket.
- Have **sufficient funds** to sustain yourself. If you plan to use credit cards bring a recent account statement showing enough money that you can live off during the vacation.
- As a freelancer, you may have an ongoing project for a customer that continues after you return. Have a copy of the contract with addresses etc. to show that you have a reason to return. As an employee, have your **work contract.**
- Same with your **home.** Have a copy of the lease or proof of ownership.
- Any **family** staying home helps. Provide names, relation and contact data.
- Prepare a detailed, documented narrative of **what you are planning to do** in the U.S. That could be a little folder with a map, rental contracts for AirBnB, hotel bookings, RVs, rental cars, contact addresses etc. Have a written schedule showing where you plan to go on which day. If you are staying with friends the entire time (hence no accommodation booking), have their address and phone. Be ready to explain how you can stay there for so many weeks. If you actually don't know exactly what you're gonna do — a lack of planning which the type of person who is an immigration officer may not understand — invent a few brush strokes that stay as close to the truth as possible. Make sure it's plausible though with money, time and the rest of the story. National Parks are always a great idea, in fiction as well as in fact ;-).

Now, this is likely overkill: Probably, the officer will only look at a few key items (ticket, money), if at all. But if push comes to shove you are prepared: You'll tell a good story that makes sense, fits the available facts and that they are happy to hear. You'll not be insecure and start stuttering or improvising.

Addendum: As it happens, the Guardian has [a story today](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2022/jun/08/australian-traveller-strip-searched-held-in-us-prison-and-deported-over-little-known-entry-requirement) about an Australian young man, Mr. Dunn, who was detained on arrival in the U.S. and eventually sent back. The specific circumstances of his detention are deplorable and somewhat traumatic, but the story supports most of the points I listed (return ticket, funds, ties to home, consistent story corroborated by evidence):

> He was interrogated by a US Customs and Border Protection (CBP) officer, who refused him entry after determining that he had **not booked onward travel** beyond Mexico.

(This is somewhat remarkable as Mexico is already outside the U.S., which should satisfy the officer. But the officer was perhaps concerned that the cheap trip to Mexico was only a pretense.)

> Dunn tried booking a flight to Panama, but **did not have enough money in his debit card account.** [...] The officer also questioned Dunn about his inability to book the onward flight out of Mexico, and **whether he had enough money to support himself** in the US.

The administration concluded:

> “You are inadmissible for admission into the United States … because of your inability to overcome the presumption of an intended immigrant. You have **no ties or equities to your home country or sufficient funds to support yourself** for your intended period of stay,” he was told at the end of the interrogation.

Comment: If you're freelancing and travelling for a work meeting that's going to look suspicious to them, as you could remain there working. It's odd for an American company to contract a freelancer from overseas, so you should look at how you explain and demonstrate that (I guess you do something very niche that nobody in the US can do). If you're travelling for a business meeting, you could even ask for a letter from the company you're visiting to explain this, which you can show to immigration. If travelling for a trade show etc, you should have some kind of proof.

Comment: @StuartF OMG, I didn't mean to suggest that you are traveling to the U.S. on a tourist visa (-waiver) in order to perform freelance work there. That's a big no-no and *exactly* the impression you should make every effort to avoid. No, if you are *a freelancer at home* on a strict tourist trip in the U.S. you should have the *home contract* that proves that you have an ongoing customer relationship *at home* that you want to return to. As an (inferior) substitute to a steady employee contract *at home.*

Answer (score 2):

I have a journalist friend who was an editor at a very prominent counterculture publication and reliably, always, 100% of the time got pulled aside for extra screening when crossing borders. He had a name for the face they make when they spot his name on the list, I forget what he called it but it was frequent enough that he gave it a name. But, he always got through. So, based on that, I'd venture to guess that as long as you didn't do anything worse than have your name regularly published in the masthead of a nationally-known counterculture magazine, you'll probably be ok, although if you are on a list you may have more secondary screenings to look forward to in the future.